# designing domain model that can handle large number of data filters?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I'm currently working on a project that I came into several years after it was built. The code is mostly procedural with a few objects that act more like buckets of functions than anything else. I want to start fixing it up by consolidating the database access and external API calls into domain models.

I have the general idea down, but I don't know how to handle getting lists of my data when I have multiple filters. Having methods called `$HelpRequestMapper->getById($id)` work fine, but what do I do when the user wants to do multiple filters?

Should I have methods for each possible case? Ie, `$HelpRequestMapper->getByCompanyAndUserAssignedToAndQueueAndStatusAndPriorityAndSearchString($company_id, $user_id, $queue_id, $status, $priority, $search_string)` This seems like it would get unwieldy very fast and not be much better than what we have now.

Should I pass in an array/object and build a query from it using something like `$HelpRequestMapper->getMultiple($array_of_options)` that does some magical query building stuff to get the data I want?

Should I do something else?

Thanks

Comment: Is this PHP? ...

Comment: Yes, it is in php. I don't care if the answer is in php or not, though.

Comment: PHP has libraries that emulate Linq, which might be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on the implementation of the filter, but you could look into the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and see if they are of use to you.

You could solve this by creating an abstract Filter class with a filter-method that takes a list of objects and returns a list of objects. Each type of filter (CompanyFilter, UserAssignedFilter, QueueFilter...) would be a separate class that extends filter. When creating the filter you would pass the filter criteria in the constructor, and the implementation of the filter-method would take the objects passed to it and only return the ones matching the filter.

You could then have a RequestQuery that you can push filters onto which fetches the data, runs the data through all the filters and returns the result.

Quick demo in C#

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string UserAssignedTo { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Filter
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<MyObject> Apply(IList<MyObject> list);
}

public class CompanyFilter : Filter
{
    private string _companyToFilter;

    public CompanyFilter(string companyToFilter)
    { 
        _companyToFilter = companyToFilter;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<MyObject> Apply(IList<MyObject> list)
    {
        return list.Where(x => x.Company == _companyToFilter);
    }
}

public class UserAssignedToFilter: Filter
{
    private string _userToFilter;

    public UserAssignedToFilter(string userToFilter)
    { 
        _userToFilter = userToFilter;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<MyObject> Apply(IList<MyObject> list)
    {
        return list.Where(x => x.UserAssignedTo == _userToFilter);
    }
}

public class RequestQuery
{
    public IEnumerable<MyObject> FindData(IList<Filter> filtersToApply)
    {
        IList<MyObject> data = null; //fetch data somewhere

        foreach(var filter in filtersToApply)
        {
            data = filter.Apply(data);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of boilerplate, isn't it?  If you're already in C#, why wouldn't you just hand an `IQueryable` to the consumer, and let them write `var myFilteredList = Companies.Where(x => x.UserAssignedTo == someUser);`?

Comment: There are several ways to optimize this depending on the language, and for this specific example Linq could indeed help out a lot. But I wanted to demonstrate the idea without resorting to too much language-specific tools and libraries. This code can be ported to a lot of other languages.

Comment: Thank you. I am think I am going to go with the strategy pattern, as it seems like the best fit to go into the existing structure.